# Unable to have a local variable with the same name as a global read-only variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly x=2

function test {
 local x=1
 echo ${x}
}

test
echo $x
```

The result is,

```
readonly-local-test.sh: line 6: local: x: readonly variable
2
2
```

When the variable is read-only this happens. However, if I remove the readonly restriction as below,

```
#!/bin/bash

x=2
function test {
 local x=1
 echo ${x}
}

test
echo $x
```

The result is,

```
1
2
```

Why read only global variables can't be shadowed?

Comment: You just can't redefine the `readonly` variables

Comment: Oh ok.. then that's just a design decision I guess

Answer (score 2):

Bash does not seem to be able to shadow *global* readonly variables. I suspect this is a consequence of Posix not having scopes for variables, apart from `$@`. However, *local* readonly variables can be shadowed. As there are no local variables in Posix, any of their behavior is posix-conform.

`readonly` always defines global variables. Local readonly variables can be defined inside a function using `local -r` or `declare -r` (behaves like `local` inside functions).

You can fix your script, turn all global variables into local ones*. For instance, by wrapping everything inside `main() { YOUR_SCRIPT_HERE; }; main` and replacing all `readonly` by `local -r`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
main() {
  local -r x=constant
  declare -p x
  f() {
    local x=mutable1
    declare -p x
    x=mutable2
    declare -p x
  }
  f
  declare -p x
  # x=... would not work here
}
main
```

Of course, instead of the naive fix *"wrap the **whole** script inside `main`"* you can also define your functions outside `main` for a better structure:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
main() {
  local -r x=constant
  declare -p x
  f
  declare -p x
  # x=... would not work here
}
f() {
  local x=mutable1
  declare -p x
  x=mutable2
  declare -p x
}
main
```

* Note that in both versions, `main`'s `x` (formerly a global variable) is in scope inside `f` when invoked from `main`. Therefore, local variables inside `main` behave mostly like actual global variables. Bash's scoping mechanism is a bit unusual if you are used to scoping as in programming languages like `C`. **Example:**

```
g() { local x=1; h; echo "g.x = $x"; }
h() { x=2; }
g
echo "global.x = $x";
```

… prints

```
g.x = 2
global.x =
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this behavior can be named "Work as design". You have readonly variable and the idea is you can't change the value of this variable. In bash you do not have the option to define variable which overwrite the set of such global variables.

Comment: I do realize that readonly variables shouldn't be allowed to change.  My question was about, a normal global variable can be shadowed by a local variable, whereas a readonly global variable cannot be shadowed.

Answer (score 0):

While this is definitely annoying behavior in some cases, as in the OP, I understand that ***this is an excellent feature***. Consider that a *global readonly* variable should be exactly that. Once set, *EVERYWHERE* in the script that variable has a known value. This includes within functions of whatever depth and anything brought in by source'd files.

Although this creates the potential for the conflict as described, the "usual" mitigation is to use a naming convention to differentiate between the two types: `ALL_CAPS_READONLY_GLOBAL` vs. `snake_case_local` or `camelCaseLocal`.

***Writable globals*** are the real bugaboo. I like to use a leading "_" (underbar) to indicate they are "special" and should not be modified carelessly. In fact, I often prefer to provide getter/setter functions for such values, as in:

```
declare -g _GLOBAL_FOO="default-value"

fooGet() { printf "%s"  "${_GLOBAL_FOO}"; }
fooSet() { _GLOBAL_FOO="${1:-}"; }
```

For arrays, it's more complificated, but the idea can be extended for both index and associative types. Also, I don't actually do the `fooGet()` as shown above; rather, I provide the name of the variable to receive the value of interest. Thus

```
local myVar=$(fooGet)             ## okay, but...
local myVar; fooGet --var myVar   ## nicer
fooGet --var myVar                ## works, sort-of, but avoid this!!
```

Actually, the two `fooGet` approaches work well in a single function. If a `--var VARNAME` argument is supplied, then set the value via a nameref. Otherwise, output the value to support the `$(foo)` form.

Further, if a global-writable is needed during initialization / configuration / startup, then add another function like:

```
fooFreeze() { declare -ga _GLOBAL_FOO; }
```

to "lock it down" (i.e. make it readonly while keeping the current value). This allows flexibility at the start, then makes the value immutable (and non-overrideable) once initialization is complete.